# Cordova crash : Error dispatching position change - DeadObjectException

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, fabricjs, crosswalk

My app crash sometime will I use canvas, like moving an image with the Fabricjs library. It's not all the time, It's unpredictable.

The is a log on an android 4.1.2 with cordova 5.3.3 and Croswswalk 1.2.0 (Chromium 42) but It appear on other device too.

```
10-26 12:56:32.066      397-397/? V/ActivityManager﹕ Binding process pid 10748 to record ProcessRecord{4252a3f0 10748:com.android.launcher/u0a41}
10-26 12:56:32.066      397-397/? V/ActivityManager﹕ New death recipient com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$AppDeathRecipient@4246b490 for thread android.os.BinderProxy@42490538
10-26 12:56:32.067      397-397/? V/ActivityManager﹕ New app record ProcessRecord{4252a3f0 10748:com.android.launcher/u0a41} thread=android.os.BinderProxy@42490538 pid=10748
10-26 12:56:32.070      397-397/? D/InputReader﹕ InputReader:: getSwitchState lock
10-26 12:56:32.070      397-397/? D/InputReader﹕ InputReader::getStateLocked:: return
10-26 12:56:32.070      397-397/? D/PowerManagerService﹕ setKeyboardVisibility: false
10-26 12:56:32.070      397-397/? V/ActivityManager﹕ ACT-Launching: ActivityRecord{4236bf80 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
10-26 12:56:32.073      397-467/? D/NetworkPolicy﹕ onRecv: MSG_FOREGROUND_ACTIVITIES_CHANGED pid:uid:act=10748:10041:true
10-26 12:56:32.086  10748-10748/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-26 12:56:32.126      397-434/? W/WindowStateAnimator﹕ Error dispatching position change: pos=(312.0,592.0)
    android.os.DeadObjectException
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
            at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.dispatchPositionChanged(IWindow.java:505)
            at com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.setSurfaceBoundaries(WindowStateAnimator.java:1077)
            at com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.prepareSurfaceLocked(WindowStateAnimator.java:1135)
            at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animate(WindowAnimator.java:476)
            at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$AnimationRunnable.run(WindowManagerService.java:742)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:567)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:535)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$WMThread.run(WindowManagerService.java:910)
10-26 12:56:32.131      397-434/? W/WindowStateAnimator﹕ Error dispatching position change: pos=(312.0,592.0)
    android.os.DeadObjectException
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
            at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.dispatchPositionChanged(IWindow.java:505)
            at com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.setSurfaceBoundaries(WindowStateAnimator.java:1077)
            at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner(WindowManagerService.java:9117)
            at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8273)
            at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.access$700(WindowManagerService.java:160)
            at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:7763)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$WMThread.run(WindowManagerService.java:910)
10-26 12:56:32.227  10748-10748/? I/ActivityThread﹕ Pub com.android.launcher2.settings: com.android.launcher2.LauncherProvider
10-26 12:56:32.294      124-325/? I/SurfaceTexture﹕ [com.myapp.toto/com.myapp.toto.MainActivity](this:0x42672008,api:1) abandon
10-26 12:56:32.294      124-325/? I/SurfaceTexture﹕ [com.myapp.toto/com.myapp.toto.MainActivity](this:0x42672008,api:1) destroying EGLImage dpy=0x1 img=0x426b3f58
10-26 12:56:32.294      124-325/? I/SurfaceTexture﹕ [com.myapp.toto/com.myapp.toto.MainActivity](this:0x42672008,api:1) destroying EGLImage dpy=0x1 img=0x426b23d8
10-26 12:56:32.294      124-325/? I/SurfaceTexture﹕ [com.myapp.toto/com.myapp.toto.MainActivity](this:0x42672008,api:1) destroying EGLImage dpy=0x1 img=0x42718118
10-26 12:56:32.294      124-325/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [com.myapp.toto/com.myapp.toto.MainActivity](this:0x426a8008,api:1) consumerDisconnect
10-26 12:56:32.294      153-153/? D/ADB_SERVICES﹕ closing because is_eof=1 r=-1 s->fde.force_eof=0
10-26 12:56:32.294      153-153/? D/ADB_SERVICES﹕ closing because is_eof=1 r=-1 s->fde.force_eof=0
10-26 12:56:32.294      124-325/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [com.myapp.toto/com.myapp.toto.MainActivity](this:0x426a8008,api:1) ~BufferQueue
10-26 12:56:32.294      124-325/? I/SurfaceTexture﹕ [com.myapp.toto/com.myapp.toto.MainActivity](this:0x42672008,api:-1) abandon
10-26 12:56:32.294      124-325/? I/SurfaceTexture﹕ [com.myapp.toto/com.myapp.toto.MainActivity](this:0x42672008,api:-1) ~SurfaceTexture
10-26 12:56:32.294      124-325/? I/SurfaceTexture﹕ [com.myapp.toto/com.myapp.toto.MainActivity](this:0x42672008,api:-1) abandon
10-26 12:56:32.319  10748-10748/? D/skia﹕ Flag is not 10
10-26 12:56:32.322  10748-10748/? D/dalvikvm﹕ create interp thread : stack size=32KB
10-26 12:56:32.322  10748-10748/? D/dalvikvm﹕ create new thread
10-26 12:56:32.322  10748-10748/? D/dalvikvm﹕ new thread created
10-26 12:56:32.322  10748-10748/? D/dalvikvm﹕ update thread list
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this issue out?

Comment: Don't remember but I don't think so